# Excel freezes after using macro that sends email using Collaboration Data Objects

Tags: excel, vba

I use a macro to send out emails, I am using this approach:
https://qdatalab.com/vba-macro-send-emails-using-gmail/

It works, except that after the email is sent Excel will freeze. It is only the things that are visible in the document that are "frozen". If I scroll down or switch sheet, it will update the screen.

For example if I delete a row, it will delete the row but not show it on the screen. If I switch to another sheet and back again, it will show the row has been deleted.

Is this some kind of memory problem or what might the cause be?

I am using the latest version of Windows 10 (v1903 i believe) and latest version of MS Excel.

When I close and re-open Excel everything is back to normal.

This is the code from the link:

```
Sub SendEmailUsingGmail()

    On Error GoTo Err

    Dim NewMail As Object
    Dim mailConfig As Object
    Dim fields As Variant
    Dim msConfigURL As String

    Set NewMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set mailConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    ' load all default configurations
    mailConfig.Load -1

    Set fields = mailConfig.fields

'Set All Email Properties

    With NewMail
        .Subject = "Test Mail"
        .From = "email@gmail.com"
        .To = "email2@gmail.com;email3@gmail.com"
        .CC = "email4@gmail.com"
        .BCC = ""
        .textbody = ""
    End With

    msConfigURL = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration"

    With fields
        'Enable SSL Authentication
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpusessl") = True
        'Make SMTP authentication Enabled=true (1)
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        'Set the SMTP server and port Details
        'To get these details you can get on Settings Page of your Gmail Account
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpserverport") = 465
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/sendusing") = 2

        'Set your credentials of your Gmail Account
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/sendusername") = "email@gmail.com"
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/sendpassword") = "********"

        'Update the configuration fields
        .Update

    End With
    NewMail.Configuration = mailConfig
    NewMail.Send
    MsgBox ("Mail has been Sent")

Exit_Err:

    Set NewMail = Nothing
    Set mailConfig = Nothing
    End

Err:
    Select Case Err.Number

    Case -2147220973  'Could be because of Internet Connection
        MsgBox " Could be no Internet Connection !!  -- " & Err.Description

    Case -2147220975  'Incorrect credentials User ID or password
        MsgBox "Incorrect Credentials !!  -- " & Err.Description

    Case Else   'Rest other errors
        MsgBox "Error occured while sending the email !!  -- " & Err.Description
    End Select

    Resume Exit_Err

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line of code is last one that executed before freeze?

Comment: It's really hard to say as it does not completely freeze (as explained in the example). I tried to run it step by step, each time trying to edit the sheet. In this case nothing froze. But running the sub will make it freeze.

Comment: Maybe it's stupid, but did you try at the end `DoEvents` folowed by `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`?

Comment: @2by So maybe it's better to show your code?

Comment: @FaneDuru I tried setting the screenupdating to false and true at the end of the macro without luck. What is the DoEvents?

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak my code is the same as in the link, I have changed the email and password though

Comment: @2by:  DoEvents function temporarily pauses a running macro, giving Excel a chance to process its own events or OS messages...

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak: And doesn't make any problem on your installation?

Comment: @2by:  Can you post here a link to your workbook? Of course, with dummy user and password...

Comment: @FaneDuru I have a macro in my personal workbook that takes data from any active workbook and sends out an email. Do you know any way to debug this? Does the script work for you without freezing Excel?

Comment: Which script? Even in the linked page there are more ways of sending CDO mails. I do not know what your code sends If it " takes data from any active workbook", I cannot imagine the size and type of what is being sent... Is the code in discussion so big and cannot be pasted in your initial post, if a dummy workbook cannot be shared?

Comment: Appreciate the help @FaneDuru, I updated the question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the MsgBox. After deleting `MsgBox ("Mail has been Sent")` it works perfectly.

Found the solution here: [Using CDO.sys dll for sending messages in VBA freezes Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326781/using-cdo-sys-dll-for-sending-messages-in-vba-freezes-excel)

Seems like a bug.